# Name this science fiction novel dealing with population explosion and pollution

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to recollect the name of a English-language sci-fi novel dealing primarily with a dystopian future with

- Explosive population growth
- Widespread global pollution
- one of the antagonists is a cult leader who preaches to people to voluntarily commit suicide to reduce burden on society
- There is some backdrop story to this antagonist in which he is revealed to be a sadist torturing little animals
- The protagonist races against time to find a solution for the pollution which is becoming lethal
- he uses notes from his late son who was a researcher in the field to follow a trail. The research notes are in a data pad that self erases if certain questions, devised by his son, are not answered when reading it
- the solution he finds at the end is a secret lab that has been growing super-intelligent next generation kids who have the potential to solve all the problems.

I remember reading it around 2002. Though I think it is a 1970-80s work.

Can you help me find the name of the novel?

Comment: @NiallC. updated my question with the details asked for.

Comment: @Flimzy English-language

Comment: Are you sure you're not conflating a couple of different books? Most notably Harry Harrison's Make Room! Make Room! (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_Room!_Make_Room!) which was made into the Soylent Green movie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green)

Comment: @ClaraOnager It definitely is not either. The only link between your suggestions and my unknown story is Population. I am sure in the story looking for there is no cannibalism.

Comment: A few points would also match some chapters of George R.R. Martins SciFi Novel Tuf Voyaging (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuf_Voyaging)

Comment: Haviland Tuf is aboard a starship, is not a sadist, nor does he use notes from a son (never had any, as I recall).

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like "Nature's End" by Whitley Strieber & James Kunetka.

- Explosive population growth

Ironically (as I type, the actual world population is quoted as 7.12 billion according to [The US Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov/popclock/)) this is set at 'over 7 billion' but the 'Depopulationist Manifesto' is quoted as saying:

> The reason that life on earth is in danger of destruction is that there is an overpopulation of human beings.

- Widespread global pollution

The first chapter has the son (Tom Sinclair) of the protagonist John Sinclair dying trying to save others "in the Denver pollution catastrophe of 2021".

- One of the antagonists is a cult leader who preaches to people to voluntarily commit suicide to reduce burden on society

This character is Gupta Singh, the head of the Depopulationist Movement.

> Every person who joins the Depopulation will gain much from his death and rise far in his next life.

- There is some backdrop story to this antagonist in which he is revealed to be a sadist torturing little animals

> Once I got a cat and tied it by its tail under the window, and cut a small slit in its belly. It screamed and squirmed about, and once in a while I would stick my fingers inside -

- The protagonist races against time to find a solution for the pollution which is becoming lethal

This is the only thing that doesn't match. They are racing to complete a 'conviction' - a computer simulacrum of a personality which can be questioned and will always tell the truth about the person it is simulating.

- He uses notes from his late son who was a researcher in the field to follow a trail. The research notes are in a data pad that self erases if certain questions, devised by his son, are not answered when reading it

This follows the description of Tom's datafiles exactly, although I can't find the quote.

- The solution he finds at the end is a secret lab that has been growing super-intelligent next generation kids who have the potential to solve all the problems.

It's not a lab, but a secret community of hyper-intelligent children and uplifted apes called "Magic".

Incidentally, this is one of my favourite books! :)

Answer (score 2):

Very vaguely like [Beggars in Spain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_in_Spain) by Nancy Kress.

There are a series of books in the series, strangely utopian turns dystopian model.

Comment: checked that one and the series, it is not the one.

Answer (score -2):

'Stand on Zanzibar', 'Shockwave Rider', or 'The Sheep Look Up' by John Brunner?

Comment: Can you explain why these match the question?

Comment: I've read all three of these multiple times -- The Sheep Look Up is the closest (deals deeply with pollution and environmental disaster, and features the reluctant leader of a cult who is trying to save the world from humanity), but lacks any of the plot elements about suicide, sadism, or the self-erasing data pad.