# looking for the title of a book about an overpopulated Earth and a messianic saviour with an intense hatred of human beings

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am searching for the title of a dystopic future/science fiction novel from the 80's (perhaps early 90's). Earth is overpopulated, resources are near exhausted, etc. One of the premises is that the main antagonist, a messianic saviour type, preaches that the only way to save humanity is if some, if not much, of the population must sacrifice their lives in order to save Earth.

There is a band of protagonists that are on a journey to find something or discover the truth about this antagonist. We discover near the end of the novel that the antagonist's motive behind his philosophy is his intense hatred of humanity. The novel is not *Logan's Run*.

Comment: My life story...

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like "[*Nature's End*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/394986.Nature_s_End)" by Whitley Strieber & James Kunetka.

> This character is "Gupta Singh" the head of the "**Depopulationist**
>   Movement". "Every person who joins the Depopulation will gain much
>   from his death and rise far in his next life."
>
> There is some backdrop story to this antagonist in which he is
>   revealed to be a sadist torturing little animals

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43380/11882